# Modify the size of R leaflet markers

Tags: r, leaflet, markers

Does somenone know if it is possible to reduce the size of R leaflet markers?

**Please find below a reproductible example**

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet(data = quakes[1:80,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(mag), label = ~as.character(mag))
```

I would like to reduce the size of these markers in order to distinguish them better. Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [R Leaflet docs](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html#customizing-marker-icons) have a section on customising marker icons.

They show that if you point to an image (you are currently pointing to the default image) then you can adjust the size and location parameters. Here is the code they give:

```
greenLeafIcon <- makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94,
  shadowUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-shadow.png",
  shadowWidth = 50, shadowHeight = 64,
  shadowAnchorX = 4, shadowAnchorY = 62
)

leaflet(data = quakes[1:4,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = greenLeafIcon)
```

So if you point to the image you want and reduce the `iconWidth` value you should achieve what you asked for.

Comment: Any way to do this for the built in AwesomeIcons? ex: made with makeAwesomeIcon from leaflet package